# C# .net application openfile Dialog works in win xp not in win 7 (32 bit or 64 bit)

Tags: c#

```
public void spawnVr_Monthly() {
    vrMonthlyProcessingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(process_Vr_Monthly_File));
    vrMonthlyProcessingThread.Start();
}
public void process_Vr_Monthly_File() {
     OpenFileDialog vrmpf = new OpenFileDialog();
     vrmpf.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true;
     vrmpf.Title = "Select VR Monthly Parking file to process";
     vrmpf.Filter = "VR Monthly Parking File (VRMTHY_OUT*.TXT|*.TXT";
 }
```

Comment: Do you actually show the dialog?  The code you've shown is incomplete.

Comment: OpenFileDialog cannot be used on a worker thread that is not STA.  See Thread.SetApartmentState() for details.  Whatever version of .NET you used on that XP machine forgot to warn you about that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `[STAThread]` attribute on your Main() function?

And I think you'd better spawn this dialog on UI thread not just any background. Use SynchronizationContext or Control.Invoke() to run something on UI thread.